# Find PlaceHolder another PlaceHolder

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, controls

I've strange problem... :/

I have on my page PlaceHolder, where I generate dynamically more PlaceHolders.
I've stored names of this dynamicaly created PlaceHolders.
When I try to find any of this PlaceHolders - I've got error null reference to an Object.

Please help! :)

```
 private void btnMoreInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;

            string[] componentName = button.ID.Split('_');


            String controlName  = null;

            foreach (String singlePlaceHolder in placeHolderNames)
            {
                if (singlePlaceHolder.Contains(componentName[0]))
                    controlName = singlePlaceHolder;
            }

            Control cph = this.Master.FindControl(controlName);

            Label helperlabel = new Label();
            helperlabel.Text = "That one!";
            cph.Controls.Add(helperlabel);
            cph.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Code breaks here:   Control cph = this.Master.FindControl(controlName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code to this, and it's working now:

```
var cph = FindControlRecursive(this.Master, controlName);
```

plus I added new method:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
 if(root.Id==id)
 {
   return root;
 }
 foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
 {
   Control t= FindControlRecursaive(c, id);
   if (t !=null)
   {
     return t;
   }
 }
return null;
}
```